# open (and maintain) remote connection with python

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, scp

I'm using Python to transfer (via scp) and database a large number of files.  One of the servers I transfer files to has odd ssh config rules to stop too many ssh requests from a single location.  The upshot of this is that my python script, currently looping through files and copying via os.system, hangs after a few files have been transferred.

Is there a way in which Python could open up an ssh or other connection to the server, so that each file being transferred does not require an instance of ssh login?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) module.

There's a [Copy files over SSH using paramiko](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576810-copy-files-over-ssh-using-paramiko/) recipe using it that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SFTP in the Python module [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).  You can do multiple file transfers in a single session.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really python specific, but it probably depends on what libraries you can use.

What you need is a way to send files through a single connection. 
(This is probably better suited to superuser or severfault.com though.)

- Create tarfile locally, upload it and unpack at target?

  - Maybe you could even run 'tar xz' remotely and upload the file on stdin over SSH? (As MichaelDillon says in the comment, Python can create the tarfile on the fly...)
- Is SFTP an option?
- Rsync over SSH?
- Twisted is an async library that can handle many sockets/connections at once. Is probably overkill for your solution though,

Hope it helps.

Comment: I should have added - data is being created and stored over a number of months, so the option to tar and send is not viable as new files will be constantly created!

Comment: @radpotato: I assumed the SSH-limit is x connections per y minutes, in which case you could batch the files. But SFTP seems to be the way to go anyhow.. :)

Comment: You can actually create a tar file on the fly inside Python as you are sending files so that the receiving end gets only a single file. And if the receiving end is running `tar xf -` then you never actually store the tarfile anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelDillon: Precisely. That was what I meant, but failed to write.